# ZF1 Routing Not working for View Script Sub-directories

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework-routing

I am using ZF1 and am trying to figure out why the view/scripts sub directories routing is not working. Here is the code from the bootstrap adding the routes. Please let me know what I may have wrong. Thanks for your time.

```
public function _initRoutes()
{


    $controller = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();

    $router = $controller->getRouter();

            //Route for user Account
    $account = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
        'ecommerce/account/:action',
        array(
            'module'     => 'ecommerce',
            'controller'     => 'user_account',
            'action'     => 'index'
        )
    );

            //Route for user Cart
            $cart = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
        'ecommerce/cart/:action',
        array(
            'module'     => 'ecommerce',
            'controller'     => 'user_cart',
            'action'     => 'index'
        )
    );
            //die(print_r($account));
            $router->addRoute('ecommerce/user_account/', $account);
            $router->addRoute('ecommerce/user_cart/', $cart);
}
```

Comment: When you say it is 'not working', what error do you get?

Comment: "We're sorry but the page you requested was not found on this website. This could be due to a number of reasons. The page could have been renamed or no longer exists. Please check the URL and try again. If you came to this page by clicking a link from another page please help us make this website more user-friendly by reporting the problem here."

Comment: So, a 404 page? Can you give an example of a URL which is giving the 404, and provide a little more detail about your controllers (class name and file location)

Comment: The structure is like this module/views/scripts/user/account
                           module/views/scripts/user/cart
I need the bootstrap to route us to the index of each sub directory by using the _ in the URI

Comment: That will happen by default with the routes you have, so we need to figure out why this isn't currently working. It could be down to the class name or location of your controllers which is why I asked for that info. E.g. your user_cart controller should live at `application/modules/ecommerce/controllers/User/CartController.php` and be a class called `Ecommerce_User_CartController` (case sensitive)

Comment: Thank you this was extremely helpful. It is routing correctly now. I had user instead of User as the directory name.

Answer (score -1):

you have to try this code

```
$router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$router1 = $router->getRouter();
$router1->addRoute('category/:id/:name/*',
        new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('category/:user_id/:user_name/*', array(
        'controller' => 'user',
        'action'     => 'index'
        ))
);
```

This will help you.